# How does cfdisk fix my disk image?

Tags: mount, loop-device

I'm working on a huge complex application. You connect a disk, press a button, and it partitions and formats the disk, mounts it, and copies some files onto it.

To test this application, we have a test system which loop-mounts a disk image and runs through the same process. Except we changed the application logic, and now the test system doesn't work. If you give the program a *real* disk, everything works fine. But if you give it a loop device, it fails.

Specifically, the application partitions the disk, formats it, and then whines that it can't mount the partition. The exact command is

```
mount /dev/vda /mnt --rw -o offset=111149056,sizelimit=314572800
```

(Here `/dev/vda` is merely a symlink to `/dev/loop0`. It makes no difference if I refer to `loop0` directly.)

If I run the command by hand, I get this:

```
root# mount /dev/vda /mnt --rw -o offset=111149056,sizelimit=314572800
FUSE exfat 1.0.1
ERROR: exFAT file system is not found.
root# echo $?
1
```

I can run this command over and over again, and it just doesn't work. No reason, it just doesn't.

Here is the terrifying part: If I run `cfdisk /dev/vda` and then immediately quit without changing anything, *now it mounts!!*

What the *hell* does `cfdisk` do to the disk that makes it suddenly start working? And how can I remove the need to call this program?

(I tried in vain to call `sfdisk -R /dev/vda`; it just complains about "invalid parameter" or something.)

I can kludge the application to call `cfdisk -Ps /dev/vda` or something, but I would really, really rather not do that. I want to find out *why* any of this is even necessary. Before we changed the application, everything worked fine...

Comment: Check the contents of /proc/partitions before and after cfdisk and see if anything changes. Additionally: when it _does_ mount, what filesystem is used? Does it help if you explicitly tell mount what filesystem to use if it's not exfat?

Comment: Correct filesystem is ext4. I will take a look at `/proc/partitions`...

Comment: Is the type always ext4?  If so use, `mount -t ext4 /dev/vda /mnt --rw -o offset=111149056,sizelimit=314572800`.  The -t option specifies the filesystem type.

Comment: MD5 of `/proc/partitions` doesn't ever change. Adding `-t ext4` causes the error text to change to `wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a small change to the test framework, and the problem went away.

Specifically, rather than calling `kpartx -u /dev/vda` after I repartition the device, I call `kpartx -d` followed by `kpartx -a`. And now everything is fine. Weird...

Answer (score 1):

A stab in the dark, but maybe `cfdisk` updates the kernel partition table when it runs?

Is your application logic compatible with loop devices?

1. Format the disk image file, creating your desired partitions
2. Setup the loopback device using the `-P` option to update the kernel's partition table:

   `losetup -P /dev/loop0 <image file>`
3. Mount the partition: `mount /dev/loop0p1 /mnt`

This way, there is no need to bother with offsets and your `mount` command is closer to the one you'd use with a real disk. You could presumably add another step between 2 and 3 to create a symlink as you have.

Comment: We deliberately moved away from using partition nodes so that we don't have to rely on the OS to correctly parse the partition table(s). We have code that reads the MBR and/or GPT and figures out all the correct offsets automatically. And until today, it's all worked fine. I don't know what's so different about _this_ setup that it fails with loop devices, yet works with real ones...

Comment: Frankly, chances are reasonable that your homebrewed solution has bugs, that the kernel or `partx` code already fixed. As for cfdisk - check kernel buffer to see what kernel thought when you used `cfdisk`.

Comment: Turns out using `/dev/mapper/loop0p1` doesn't work anyway...

Answer (score 1):

The kernel first has to learn about the partitions. Once you partition a loop device (say `/dev/loop0`) you can't really mount it as such (the partition obviously doesn't begin at the beginning of the device). For physical drives you can instruct the kernel to re-read the partition table (at least fro (S)ATA drives) with `hdparm -z`.

Another option is to use a special utility, that will scan the device for a partition table (not necessarily just GPT or MBR) and create the partition device files for you. One of those is `partx` (comes with util-linux).

Comment: The test framework already has logic to run `kpartx` and symlink all the device nodes it creates, such that `/dev/vda`, `/dev/vda1`, `/dev/vda2`, etc exist - just like with a real disk.

Comment: OK, in that case you probably want to include that in the question. You should also say, what are you using for formatting the partitions etc.